# Pandas dataframe, if a value in a column has a duplicate, check if a specific value in another column is different and then change it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, in this dataframe I have 2 rows with duplicate values(ABCD, TG) in 2 columns(sequence and ID) and a different value in the 3rd column(group).

How would I check the whole dataframe for any instances where there are duplicate values in these 2 columns(sequence and ID) and if the **group** value is also different then change group value from 0 to 1.

| SEQUENCE | ID | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | TG | 0 |
| BACD | LK | 0 |
| ABCD | TG | 1 |

I would like an output like this:

| SEQUENCE | ID | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | TG | 1 |
| BACD | LK | 0 |
| ABCD | TG | 1 |

Thank you for any solutions and suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not the most concise way for doing this but it seems to provide the desired result:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'SEQUENCE': ['ABCD', 'BACD', 'ABCD'],
    'ID': ['TG', 'LK', 'TG'],
    'Group': [0, 0, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)


def check_duplicates(df, seq, elem_id, group):
    
    different_groups = True if df[(df.SEQUENCE == seq) & (df.ID == elem_id)]['Group'].nunique() > 1 else False 
    sequence_dupls = True if len(df[df.SEQUENCE == seq]) > 1 else False
    id_dupls = True if len(df[df.ID == elem_id]) > 1 else False
    
    if sequence_dupls and id_dupls and different_groups:
        return 1 
    else:
        return group


df['Group'] = df.apply(lambda row: check_duplicates(df, row.SEQUENCE, row.ID, row.Group), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only 0, 1 in your `Group` column, you could do groupby/transform with numpy's [`any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) The `any` function checks if any value is other than 0 if yes returns True:

```
df['Group'] = df.groupby(['SEQUENCE', 'ID']).transform(lambda x: 1 if np.any(x) else 0)
```

print(df):

```
  SEQUENCE  ID  Group
0     ABCD  TG      1
1     BACD  LK      0
2     ABCD  TG      1
```